# sendRedirect vs forward to the root path

Tags: java, redirect, requestdispatcher

I have the redirection done in this way: `response.sendRedirect("/");`
and to avoid going back to the browser and the redirect, I would like to use:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/").forward(request, response);
```

The problem is that usually, we put the name of the jsp in getRequestDispatcher and in this case I have NullPointerException.
How can I achieve the same behavior using the url?

Comment: You can't, if doing internally. Note that the URL won't change, so it could leave you on a funky state. A full redirect may be clearer to the user

Comment: you mean like this  `String url="test.jsp";  // may be servlet url or html etc
  if(url!=null&&url.length()>0) {   
   request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
  }`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I mean like in the example: request.getRequestDispatcher("/").forward(request, response);